# I am not sure how to rename factors in r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to rename levels in r shiny.

```
levid <-
  reactive( {

    if (input$ident == "NULL"){
      levels(data()@active.ident)
    } else {
      tmp <- data()
      levels(tmp@active.ident) = dput(geneid())
      data <- reactiveVal()
      data(tmp)
      levels(data()@active.ident)
    }
    
  }
      )
```

The thing is that I have multiple tabs in the shiny app in the sidebar and the data() object is used in all of them. But if the user wants to modify the certain names in the option set by the code shown above than I want that modified object to remain permanently and be used with those modifications.

data()@active has cluster names and these cluster names I want them to be renamed if the user wants it. Currently the cluster names are 1,2,3,4,5,6 but if the user wants to change it to names he like he should be able to see it in the UMAP and PCA tabs as well.

Comment: Replace `if (input$ident == "NULL"){` with `if (is.null(input$ident)){`

Comment: That did not have any effect. I know that renaming the part  dput(geneid()) is really the issue. If use add data() into a new object and that object is not reactive it seems to work but I want the reactive object to be changed. Also my current value is "NULL" and I want it to keep it that way. The "NULL" is text so not the actual NULL which you see in R.

Comment: If you post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someone might be able to help you.

Comment: I added a new piece of code at the end or a second piece which seems to work but data() object is not permanently changed.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you're trying to assign a new value to a `reactive expression` and not a `reactive value`. In other words you're trying to assign a value to a **conductor** rather than a **source** using the language described [shiny's documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html). But it's hard to tell without seeing an MRE

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example that changes the factor levels of a vector in a **reactive expression**. The key is to store the new levels in a **reactive value**, then the reactive expression can react to the change.

```
library(shiny)

dummy_dat <- rnorm(1000)

ui <- basicPage(
  h3("factors for",code("rnorm(1000)")),
  uiOutput("factors"),
  actionButton("rename","rename"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  r <- reactiveValues(
    new_levels = NULL,
  )
  
  df <- reactive({
    V1 <- dummy_dat
    V2 <- cut(V1,unique(quantile(V1)))
    if (!is.null(r$new_levels)) {levels(V2) <- r$new_levels}
    data.frame(V1,V2)
  })
  
  output$factors <- renderUI({
    textAreaInput("text_factors", "rename factors", height = "100px", 
                        value = paste(levels(df()$V2), collapse = "\n"))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$rename, {
    r$new_levels <- unlist(strsplit(isolate(input$text_factors), split = "\n"))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    head(df())
  })
  
 }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```